How to Generate a Transformation Matrix for Bicubic Interpolation on a Masked 2D Grid?
I have a set of image patches, all the same size, where 20% of the pixels are masked. I want to interpolate the missing pixels using bicubic interpolation on a regular 2D grid.
Normally, this can be done with scipy.interpolate.interp2d. However, since the mask is the same for all patches and I always interpolate the same coordinates, I’m looking for a more efficient approach.
Specifically, I want to precompute the transformation matrix A that applies to the known pixels, allowing me to interpolate the missing pixels through simple matrix-vector multiplication. This method should take advantage of the fact that bicubic interpolation is linear, so it should be possible to express the interpolation as y=A@x, where x represents the known pixel values and y represents the interpolated result. How can I construct such a transformation matrix for bicubic interpolation on a masked 2D grid?
Here is a simple code snippet:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage.util import random_noise
from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio as psnr
from scipy.ndimage import zoom

image = img_as_float(data.astronaut())
gray_image = np.mean(image, axis=2)
patch_size = 32
patch = gray_image[:patch_size, :patch_size]
mask = np.random.rand(*patch.shape) > 0.2
masked_patch = patch.copy()
masked_patch[~mask] = 0 

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))

axs[0].imshow(patch, cmap='gray')
axs[0].set_title('Original Patch')

axs[1].imshow(masked_patch, cmap='gray')
axs[1].set_title('Masked Patch')

for ax in axs:
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()

I want to interpolate Masked Patch missing pixels, but not using scipy.interpolate.interp2d, I want to get transformation matrix, which is a tall matrix, that applies to existing pixels and outputs the interpolated image.
